# Request.Body changes when a parameter is added to the route

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am working on an ASP.NET Core API that processes multipart POST requests.

Today I tried to add a parameter to the route, which triggered an `IOException` (Unexpected end of stream) when trying to call `ReadNextSectionAsync` on my `MultipartReader`.

I dumped (using [ObjectDumper](https://github.com/lassevk/ObjectDumper)) the `MultipartReader` to the log in both cases and the only difference (besides the boundary obviously) is a field of the inner stream. The stream is the `Request.Body` that I'm passing directly from the controller.

I'll show this difference with a minimal example:

```cc
[Route("foo/")]
public class FooController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<FooController> _log;

    public FooController(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _log = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<FooController>();
    }

    [HttpPost("1/bar")]
    public void Foo()
    {
        _log.LogInformation(Request.Body.DumpToString("Works"));
    }
}
```

This logs the following:

```
INFO: #1: Works [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.FrameRequestStream]
{
   properties {
      CanRead = True [System.Boolean]
      CanSeek = False [System.Boolean]
      CanWrite = False [System.Boolean]
      #2: Length = TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocat (+4 chars) [System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException]
      #3: Position = TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocat (+4 chars) [System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException]
      CanTimeout = False [System.Boolean]
      #4: ReadTimeout = TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocat (+4 chars) [System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException]
      #5: WriteTimeout = TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocat (+4 chars) [System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException]
   }
   fields {
      #6: _body [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.MessageBody+ForContentLength]
      {
         properties {
            RequestKeepAlive = True [System.Boolean]
         }
         fields {
            _contentLength = 242 [System.Int64]
            _inputLength = 242 [System.Int64]
         }
      }
      _state = Open [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.FrameStreamState]
      {
         fields {
            value__ = 0 [System.Int32]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

However, if I do this:

```
[Route("foo/")]
public class FooController : Controller
{
    // ...
    // Same logging setup
    // ...

    [HttpPost("{id:int}/bar")] // This doesn't actually need to change
    public void Foo(int id)
    {
        _log.LogInformation(Request.Body.DumpToString("Doesn't work"));
    }
}
```

The `_inputLength` field has a value of 0.
Then when I create a `MultipartReader` with this stream it fails when calling `ReadNextSectionAsync` for the first time.

This looks a bit like an ASP.NET Core bug to me but I'm new to ASP.NET so I might be missing something important!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like adding a parameter to the route triggers ASP.NET model binding, which reads the request body. After that I can't read it.

This leaves me with two options:

1. Use model binding to read the file as well
2. Not use model binding at all and find another way of getting the parameter.

I chose the second option, writing something like:

```
[HttpPost("{id:int}/bar")]
public void Foo()
{
    int id = Int32.Parse((string)RouteData.Values["id"]);

    // ...
}
```